# how to get velocity of Ar drone 2.0

Tags: quadcopter

i have question about AR Drone 2.0. i am using ROS Gazebo and Python. my question is **how to get velocity of quadcopter?** i need velocity to count position of quadcopter. Thankyou.

Comment: velocity relative to what?

Comment: @jsotola velocity when AR Drone moving forward

Comment: you did not answer my question